# Creating toolbar in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I have aplication with swipe view which is using fragments. What I want is to create separate toolbars for each fragment. Ive searched the internet and used recomended solution but my application is crashing when I try to cast MainActivity to AppCompact Activity when I want to use setSupportActionBar(). Heres the fragment class:

```
package sk.cassomedia.studentassitent.view;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import sk.cassomedia.studentassitent.R;

public class Contacts extends Fragment {

    private Toolbar toolbar;

    public Contacts() {
    // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contacts, container, false);
        AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
        toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.contacts_toolbar);
        activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        return view;
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.calendar_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static Fragment newInstance() {
        Contacts contacts = new Contacts();

        return contacts;
    }
}
```

heres the fragment layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="sk.cassomedia.studentassitent.view.Contacts">

<include
    android:id="@+id/contacts_toolbar"
    layout="@layout/contacts_toolbar"></include>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="836dp"
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and toolbar xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

And error message

```
02-22 09:09:07.835 12623-12623/sk.cassomedia.studentassitent E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           java.lang.ClassCastException: sk.cassomedia.studentassitent.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity
                                                                               at sk.cassomedia.studentassitent.view.Contacts.onCreateView(Contacts.java:30)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:251)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.completeScroll(ViewPager.java:1849)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onInterceptTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:1978)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2033)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2401)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2091)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2401)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2091)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2401)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2091)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2306)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1575)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2470)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2254)
                                                                               at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7888)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3977)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3861)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5101)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5080)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5179)
                                                                               at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
                                                                               at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
                                                                               at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:138)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

MainActivity

```
package sk.cassomedia.studentassitent;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;


import sk.cassomedia.studentassitent.controllers.FragmentAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    static final int NUMBER_OF_SCREENS = 3;

    private FragmentAdapter adapter;
    private ViewPager viewPage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        adapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPage = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPage.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Log message if I change main activity to extends AppCompat Activity

```
02-22 09:15:26.757 14192-14192/sk.cassomedia.studentassitent E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           java.lang.ClassCastException: sk.cassomedia.studentassitent.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity
                                                                               at sk.cassomedia.studentassitent.view.Contacts.onCreateView(Contacts.java:30)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:251)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.completeScroll(ViewPager.java:1849)
                                                                               at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onInterceptTouchEvent(ViewPager.java:1978)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2033)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2401)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2091)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2401)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2091)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2401)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2091)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2401)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2091)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2401)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2091)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2306)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1575)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2470)
                                                                               at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2254)
                                                                               at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7888)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3977)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3861)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5101)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5080)
                                                                               at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5179)
                                                                               at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
                                                                               at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
                                                                               at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:138)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
                                                                               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post your error logcat

Comment: Could you please post logcat and styles.xml

Comment: its issue with your mainactivity,,why you extend it with action bar activity

Comment: MainActivity extends FragmentActivity I will post it just sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your `MainActivity` parent class to `AppCompatActivity`.

Comment: result is same it crashes when i swipe to contacts fragment

Comment: Ive added the logcat message to question

Comment: Try changing `AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();` to `MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();`

Comment: And also change your `AppTheme` from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

Comment: Thanks for help changing it to MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity(); helped I had Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar in manifest. But can I have one more question If I have app like this with swipe view MainActivity doeasnt have to extends FragmentActivity ?

Comment: yes, In theory your MainActivity can extend FragmentActivity. But after extending FragmentActivity, you can't cast your class to AppCompatActivity. But you can use either ActionbarActivity or AppCompatActivity. These class exist to give backward compatiblity for features like actionbar or toolbar. Since you want to use toolbar you must extend `AppCompatActivity`. I hope it helped you..